# SOT-23 3.3V voltage regulator identification

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, sot23

I am looking for an assistance to identify an electronic component used in [wireless 2.4GHz wireless keyboard](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005237093610.html) for Android TV box.

The component is in SOT-23 package and perhaps 3.3V voltage regulator with marking 'C33A' and emblem resembling "a boat with a sail" (or maybe pegasus with a wing).

[image: Voltage 3.3V regulator]

My investigation indicates that pin 1 is a ground, pin 2 is output and pin 3 input (connected to a battery through a coil).

I have looked through logos of electronic components manufacturers and did not find a match. Looking through voltage regulator components on a website of couple distributors, the electronic components have different pin layout.

Comment: You mentioned that it's "connected to a battery". A single 1.5V cell, or multiple in series? In other words: What's the input voltage?

Comment: I gather it's a 1.5 to 3.3V synchronous boost regulator, but more specificity would be welcome, yeah. I've seen three-terminal regulators like this before, but I forget who makes them or what part numbers are relevant.  It's most likely a Chinese brand.

Comment: https://smd.yooneed.one/code4333.html has some devices with a SMD marking code of ``C33A``, but looking at them can't seem to find a matching device.

Comment: @ Jonathan S.
The keyboard utilizes 2 AAA batteries, so input voltage is about 3V. Spehro Pefhany was able to identify the item as QX2304L33T part made by QX Micro Devices (Shenzhen).

Answer (score 7):

It's a QX Micro Devices (Shenzhen) [QX2304L33T](https://www.lcsc.com/search?q=QX2304L33T). Datasheet [here](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_QX-Micro-Devices-QX2304L33T_C219038.pdf)

[image]

The trailing 'A' is the batch number.

From their website (no English datasheet):

Ø Maximum efficiency: 95%

Ø Maximum working frequency: 300 KHz

Ø Low quiescent current: 15uA

Ø Optional output voltage: 2.5V ～ 3.6V

Ø Output accuracy: ± 2.5%

Ø Wide input voltage range: 0.9V ～ 3.6V

Ø Low ripple and low noise

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, it looks like this is exactly what I was looking for. Although pin 2 marked as 'LX' (a little confusion) instead of 'VIN' otherwise pins match. Time to hunt where to purchace from. How did you identified electonic part -- what resources did you use?

Comment: A three-terminal boost converter? That's certainly unusual.

Comment: @Hearth It's not the only one, though, see for example https://ti.com/product/TPS61322 . That one looks like it's pin compatible and it has an english data sheet.